# Final Cut Pro add shortcut for positional keyframe

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, finalcut

I am new to Final Cut Pro so I am sorry if the question is confusing. I am attempting to set a keyboard shortcut that will set a keyframe for the position, rotation, scale, scale X, Scale Y, and Anchor all in one keyboard shortcut. Basically the entire transform page. After performing this keyboard shortcut it should add a keyframe to all of this on the selected clip. If possible I would like for it to be able to do this for clips and images at the same time but I don't know if that is possible. This would all happen at the playhead. Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh well for anyone thinking the same thing a solution is to just select all of those points at the start and then move the playhead to where you want and then move your object and it will do the rest for you.